# Порядок foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

Хотел сделать вызов определенного forech в зависимости от того, какой игрок ходит, но при любом случае, срабатывает только первый, не смотря на ход. Не могу понять из-за чего.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Значит косяк в методе, который вызывается в условии.

Comment: если у вас выполняется всегда только первый цикл, то это означает, что у вас условие всегда true, независимо от хода игрока, проверьте, как работает getTurn1()

Comment: @eXit Работает правильно, но даже если поменять условие или сами циклы, то все равно выполняется первый

Comment: @ИльяКрылов Ну так не бывает...

Comment: Поставьте точку останова и посмотрите, какое значение там возвращается.